# How to make window resize not take any change

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a question:
How to make a responsive design that when I resize the window the design not change at all(width, height, positions), only the window cover the design/content.

For example this website: https://www.zap.co.il/

How can I dot it if all elements are viewports and almost every element positioned absolutely to the body tag ?
For the viewports I can use SVG - It solving it, but the position ?

I want everything remain the same, thank for your help

Comment: So you actually want the _opposite_ of a responsive design … Well that should probably start with specifying a min-width for a container element. And then probably modifications to the viewport meta tag. (All in all, I’d say this is one of those questions that is just way too broad. Y’all try to circumvent actually putting in the time and learning some of the necessary basics, especially when it comes to CSS layouts, by asking your “how to” questions here all day long.)

Answer (score 1):

this should make your page basically responsive

then for resizing components at different widths

```
`<meta charset="utf-8">` html code


 @media screen and (min-width:800px){
       //css code for screen widths above 800pixels
        }
```

css code